# I can't access my localhost with xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

Initially xampp was working fine and I could access my localhost with no problem. I even set my passwords to access the server. 
For a while everything was great, xampp asked me my credentials, I inserted them and I was taken to my administrator page. No problem.

One time though, I had to change the ports used for Apache, but afterwards it didn't complain anymore.

Now I receive a message saying Google Chrome could not connect to my localhost.
Everything seems to be working so I don't know what's wrong.

This is what I see on xampp control panel:

Initializing Control Panel

```
14:57:04  [main]    Windows Version: Windows Vista Home Premium SP2 32-bit
14:57:04  [main]    XAMPP Version: 1.8.3
14:57:04  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
14:57:04  [main]    You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
14:57:04  [main]    most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
14:57:04  [main]    there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
14:57:04  [main]    about running this application with administrator rights!
14:57:04  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
14:57:04  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
14:57:04  [main]    All prerequisites found
14:57:04  [main]    Initializing Modules
14:57:04  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
14:57:04  [main]    Control Panel Ready
14:57:06  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
14:57:06  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
14:57:08  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
14:57:08  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will need to specify the new port number in your browser: `http://localhost:10101` if the port is 10101.

Answer (score 4):

You have to check the port number and add it along with the localhost. For example the port that I use is 8080, So it has to be localhost:8080/dashboard

Comment: Does anyone know what the actually cause to this is? Sometime localhost is acceptable, then at other times I will need the port number.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you need to change the Port Number.

you do it in the server control panel.
Press the config button Go inside the httpd.conf document and change the port number on your behalf.

To load it type `localhost:"Your chosen port number"` in the url field.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a short remark because this question is associated with another common question -- ["XAMPP Port 80 in use by “Unable to open process” with PID 4 [duplicate]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317372/xampp-port-80-in-use-by-unable-to-open-process-with-pid-4)

Given that the common solution for the previous question is

> Now it avoids Port 80 and uses Port 8080 instead without issue. The only additional thing you need to do is make sure to put localhost:8080 in the browser so the browser knows to look on Port 8080. Otherwise it defaults to Port 80 and won't find your local site.

the exact number to be specified in your browser is `http://localhost:8080` rather than `http://localhost:10101`.

For more information, please have a look at [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blmOFr8uZQI)

Comment: My first answer on Stack Overflow. Feel appreciated for your selfless supports.