# XAMPP installed, Port 80 & 443 in use, administrator rights

Tags: php, apache, xampp, port80

Today I reinstalled XAMPP after it and all other downloaded programs had to be wiped off my PC during a recent de-virusing. This was a completely standard XAMPP install: I left all the pre-selected components checked and made sure to install to C:\xampp.

Even after following the instructions in this thread (i.e, I changed "Listen 80" to "Listen 8080" in httpd.conf and saved the file):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24423669/5895638

I am still getting this when I launch XAMPP Control Panel:

```
11:30:36 AM  [main]     Initializing Control Panel
11:30:36 AM  [main]     Windows Version: Windows 7 Professional SP1 32-bit
11:30:36 AM  [main]     XAMPP Version: 5.6.15
11:30:36 AM  [main]     Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
11:30:36 AM  [main]     You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
11:30:36 AM  [main]     most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
11:30:36 AM  [main]     there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
11:30:36 AM  [main]     about running this application with administrator rights!
11:30:36 AM  [main]     XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
11:30:36 AM  [main]     Checking for prerequisites
11:30:36 AM  [main]     All prerequisites found
11:30:36 AM  [main]     Initializing Modules
11:30:36 AM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
11:30:36 AM  [Apache]   Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 2264!
11:30:36 AM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:30:36 AM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:30:36 AM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
11:30:36 AM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
11:30:36 AM  [Apache]   Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 2264!
11:30:36 AM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:30:36 AM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:30:36 AM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
11:30:36 AM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
11:30:36 AM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
```

All the help topics I can find on this issue discuss only Port 80 and PID 4--which is not the PID number I am getting (above) with Port 80. I also seem to have issues with Port 443 and administrator rights. Please advise what I should do (as I have no idea). **Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

Simply run as Administrtor "`xampp-control.exe`"

Comment: Thanks, Druge, but . . . how do I do that?

Comment: right click on your installed xampp(mostly comes in desktop)  file and there comes the option "Run as administrator"

Comment: Did that, got this (no red in it) in XAMPP Control Panel: [main] Initializing Control Panel
[main] Windows Version: Windows 7 Professional SP1 32-bit
[main] XAMPP Version: 5.6.15
[main] Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
[main] Running with Administrator rights - good!
[main] XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
[main] Checking for prerequisites
[main] All prerequisites found
[main] Initializing Modules
[Apache] XAMPP Apache is already running on port 80
[Apache] XAMPP Apache is already running on port 443
[main] Starting Check-Timer
[main] Control Panel Ready

Comment: What should I think of the fact that it says "XAMPP Apache is already running on port 80 (and port 443)"? Is that a problem, or is my XAMPP installation now running trouble-free?

Comment: Also, is there some way I can configure XAMPP so that every time I want to start it, I don't have to right-click it and select "Run as Administrator"?